# Can't cancel order in pending status

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I created an order payment with Redsys. The status of the order is Pending. However I can't cancel the order. Appears a message saying that "the order can't be canceled"
Why? In theory, I could cancel a order in pending.

Anyone knows what happen?

Thanks.

I'm in Magento 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

I found out something. It's because redsys payment generate invoice. If I go inside of the order invoice and I cancel that invoice I can cancel de order. Now the question is, why create an invoice by default? how could I fix it?

Thanks, I hope your answer.